# Making Chrome Extension, can't assign global variable properly in js-file (single file)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Strange error, says `config` is `undefined`, but that is false:

[image]

There is no misspellings:

[image: Image of Error]

I am not JavaScript programmer, and that is my first extension.  I hope it is a known issue. The only thing used is AJAX. The code starts like this:

```
var config;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    config = JSON.parse(this.response);
  }
}
req.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('/config.json'), true);
req.send();
// here console.log(config) will return undefined.
```

In other words variable is assigned strangely.

Comment: Another time, please provide a *complete* [mcve]. At an **absolute minimum** you needed to supply the line on which the error occurred. Nowhere in your code are you trying to access the `currency` property. Thus, this is incomplete. In general, for Chrome extension debugging questions, you almost always need to supply a *manifest.json*.

Answer (score 1):

Since `XMLHTTPRequest`s are asynchronous (they don't happen instantly as the code flows) you'll have to either put the code inside their load event listener, or call a function that will have that code in it from the same event listener:

```
var config;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    config = JSON.parse(this.response);

    // any code that uses config should be here
  }
}
```

or:

```
var config;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    config = JSON.parse(this.response);

    // call doMagicStuff here
    doMagicStuff();
  }
}

function doMagicStuff() {

    // code that use config goes here

}
```

in the latter, you might as well just pass `config` as parameter to `doMagicStuff`.